# Vamos desregistrar o [registro] e eliminar os [duplicados] das [colunas]

Tags: debate, tags

Mais três tags inúteis que temos que esvaziar e mandar para o espaço:

- [registro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registro) - 27 perguntas.
- [duplicados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duplicados) - 16 perguntas.
- [colunas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colunas) - 42 perguntas.

A meu ver, todas elas são inúteis. Nenhuma delas têm wiki com descrição.

Se ninguém se opor, podemos começar os esforços para eliminar essas tags, a serem realizados em horários de pouco movimento no site, tal como de noite ou durante o natal.

Comment: Se são desnecessárias, sou a favor de eliminá-las também, só salientando o que você já disse, em horário de pouco movimento como após as 19 horas(brasilia) ou manha/noite de fim de semana.

Comment: A tag registro, combinada com outras, não é util não? Digo, como registro de dominios, etc...

Comment: @Articuno É uma tag ambígua, pois registro pode significar um monte de coisas. Além disso, para isso já temos [domínio] e [dns].

Comment: Outra tag inútil, ao meu ver, é [apple](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/apple/info)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As tags já foram esvaziadas. Missão concluída com sucesso!